# css dropdown sub menu not dropping under parent menu item

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, cascadingdropdown

I have a simple css dropdown menu but the sub menus don't seem to drop right below their parent menu. Here a link to what it currently looks like.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/centem/k7C9T/2/)

Please help. Thank you.

************* here is the html**********************

```
<header>
<table>
      <td>
      <h1>Header</h1>
        <nav>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">menu1</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">sub</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">sub</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">sub</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">menu2</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">sub</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">sub</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">sub</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">menu3</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">sub</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">sub</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">sub</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">menu4</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">sub</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">sub</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">sub</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
    </td>
    </table>
</header>
```

****************** here is the css ****************************

```
table {
border: 1px solid black;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
header {
position: absolute;
top:0;
width: 100%;
border: 1px solid black;
}
header h1 {
display: inline-block;
}
nav {
display: inline-block;
}
nav ul {
list-style-type: none;
}
nav li {
display: inline;
}
nav ul ul li a{
display: block;
}
nav li ul {
display: none;
}
nav li:hover ul{
display:block;
}
nav ul ul li{
display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need a couple small changes to make the nested `ul`s appear relative to their parent `li`:

```
nav li {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}

nav li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It appears that all menu items only dropdown below the first menu item only. How can I get them to dropdown their own parent menu.

Comment: Here, I've updated your fiddle to incorporate the changes I suggested: http://jsfiddle.net/k7C9T/5/